# ev.target.id does not return element id

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

What is the problem and solution? I couldn't find any bug here

**This is the drop point:**

```
<div class="drophere" id="drophere_215" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="http://static.myface.photos/imagedynamically.aspx?image=/images/uploads/215.jpg" />
</div>
```

**This is the drag point:**

```
<span class="draghere" id="draghere_215" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<span>Georgia</span>
</span>
```

**And this is the js code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev){
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var shortData = data.replace('draghere_','');
  var dropElement = ev.target.id;

if(dropElement.indexOf(shortData) !== -1){
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).remove();
 }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the dropped target is the parent `<div>` and not the `<img>` element:

```
   function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var shortData = data.replace('draghere_','');
        var dropElement = ev.target;
        if(ev.target.tagName=="IMG")
              dropElement = $(ev.target).closest('div')[0];
        if(dropElement.id.indexOf(shortData) !== -1){
            dropElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            document.getElementById(dropElement.id).remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works now.

Comment: Any problems yet? why you didn't mark the answer as answered?

Comment: That's ok, let me know if you have more problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You need pass parameter  `this` no `event` access `id` ev.id
`e.target` is on listener
example:

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

example:

```
<div class="drophere" id="drophere_215" ondrop="drop(this)" ondragover="allowDrop(this)">
<img src="http://static.myface.photos/imagedynamically.aspx?image=/images/uploads/215.jpg" />
</div>
```

This is the drag point:

```
<span class="draghere" id="draghere_215" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(this)">
<span>Georgia</span>
</span>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var shortData = data.replace('draghere_','');
  var dropElement = ev.id;

if(dropElement.indexOf(shortData) !== -1){
ev.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
document.getElementById(ev.id).remove();
 }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I tried by using "this" instead "event" as parameter. But that was totally stopped the drag drop mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is in this line:

```
var dropElement = ev.target.id;
```

you may consider to test if the event target is the img element. In this case  you may get the closest drophere ancestor:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var shortData = data.replace('draghere_','');
    var dropElement = (ev.target.tagName == 'IMG') ? ev.target.closest('.drophere') : ev.target;

    if(dropElement.id.indexOf(shortData) !== -1){
        dropElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        document.getElementById(dropElement.id).remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="drophere" id="drophere_215" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1" />
</div>

<span class="draghere" id="draghere_215" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<span>Georgia</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I understand your suggestion. But I need exactly the id name because this name bears the image name with a additional string.

Comment: the image does not have any id, while the parent div has the id. **dropElement ** in my snippet is the element and no more the id. Indeed i changed the next lines where you used evt.target.id with dropElement.id